# Curl basic Authentication, always failed 401

Tags: php, authentication, curl

this is my curl code with basic authentication:

```
<?php

    ///CURL
    $data['item'] = 'example';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://100.100.100.100/items");
    $headr = array();
    $headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
    $headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
    $headr[] = 'SourceSystem: system';
    $headr[] = 'InteractionTime: 2017-07-13 11:06:00';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "fakeusername:fakepassword");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($output === false)
    {
        print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($info);

?>
```

With this code i have always a code 401 (Authentication Failed) in return. Before i'll talk to the server's owners to ask an example header, there's something wrong in this code? Or maybe there something i have to consider in an https server?

This is an example of a posted header:

> POST /items HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Basic FAKEBASE64PASSUSER= Host: 100.100.100.100 Content-length: 0 Accept: application/json SourceSystem: system InteractionTime: 2017-07-13 11:06:00 Expect: 100-continue Content-type: application/json; boundary=----------------------------0665dac4f062